# Latch register not showing the same value as the port register

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip, mplab, pic18

I'm writing a program on PIC18F4550 where I have data defined in my memory and want to send it to PORTA character by character. I have done so but the values showing on LATA are not the ones shown in the PORTA register. I've searched the data sheet, and it states that writing to the port will write to its latch, however, I've encountered instances where both the port and the latch register have the same values when writing to it. Is it just the case that the port and lat are not supposed to be the same, or am I doing something wrong? I'm using the simulator tool on MPLABX V5.30

```
    LIST                    p=18f4550               
    INCLUDE                 <p18f4550.inc>          
            
    ORG                     0x00                    ; Program Origin/Start Address

MAIN                                                  
    CLRF            TRISA
    MOVLW           0X0
    MOVWF           TBLPTRL
    MOVLW           0X05
    MOVWF           TBLPTRH
READ    
    TBLRD*+
    MOVF            TABLAT, W
    BZ              EXIT
    MOVWF           PORTA
    GOTO            READ    
EXIT    
    GOTO             $                       ; This Line Is To Keep The Program Running, Not To Terminate

        
        
        ORG             0x500
NAME    DB              "NAME",'0'
        END                                             ; Program End
```

Comment: It may be required to set the pins to digital I/O mode instead of analog one, which is the default value on Power-On Reset.

Comment: Yes, LAT and PORT registers are not supposed to be the same. The LATx bits are for holding the data to output out of the pin, while PORTx bits are for holding the data from the inputs. What present on the pins PORTx bits will have it. In summery; the LATx bits have the data flow in the output direction, while the PORTx bits have the data flow in the input direction.

Comment: Since the PORTA is multiplexed with the analog hardware you can't configure those multiplexed pins unless you disable their analog hardware. In the datasheet section **10.1 PORTA, TRISA and LATA Registers** there is an example **EXAMPLE 10-1: INITIALIZING PORTA** check it out. You may also need to set some config bits in order to control all PORTA pins digitally. Read carefully the section **10.1**, you will find the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

The differences between the `PORT` and `LAT` registers can be summarized as follows:
LATx-Register:
Should be used to write to a port pin. A write to the `LATx` register writes the data value to the port latch.

PORTx-Register:
Should be used to read a port pin.  A read of the `PORTx` register reads the data value on the I/O pin.
A write to the `PORTx` register writes the data value to the port latch.

And you must always select between analog and digital Pin with the `ANSEL` register. Default: analog.